# How to replace unmatched words with special character?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace equal number of unmatched characters with `*`. Like as I've string

```
xyzdsdasdas@xyss.com
```

should be replace into

```
x*********s@x**s.com
```

Right now just for work around I'm using the following regex

```
^(\w).*?(.@.).*?(.\.\w+)
```

So using that followed regex along with `preg_replace` like as

```
echo preg_replace('/^(\w).*?(.@).*?(\.\w+)/', "$1****$2****$3", "xyzdsdasdas@xyss.com");
```

which result into

```
x****s@x****s.com
```

but what I want to achieve over here is

```
x*********s@x**s.com
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/nW5iX9/3)

Comment: Downvoters please post the reason for downvoting the question

Comment: may be you should try a loop with "for" instead of preg_replace

Comment: I don't think so that's a good idea to work around

Comment: Maybe preg_replace (and regexp at all) is not the more efficient way to achieve this.

Comment: first explode two part with "@", get the count of first part replace chars with * from 2 to n-1;   with the second part replace chars with * from 2 to n-5, this is not very inteligent solution but still work

Comment: @Amessihel really? check my answer. It would be much more efficient than explode.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I didn't mean to use explode instead. :) But your answer rocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `(*SKIP)(*F)`

```
preg_replace('~(?:^.|.@.|.\.\w+$)(*SKIP)(*F)|.~', '*', $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tX6mW2/1)

- First match all the chars you don't want. ie, `(?:^.|.@.|.\.\w+$)`
- Now, skip those matches using `(*SKIP)(*F)`
- `|` OR
- Now the dot after `|` will match all the characters other than the skipped ones.

Comment: Its working fine but I didn't understand `(*SKIP)(*F)|.` part of the regex

Comment: Great Explanation. @Avi +1

Comment: @Avinash Raj, I've learnt something today. `(*SKIP)` and `(*F)` are PCRE control-verb patterns which modify the behaviour of the engine. Once a pattern is matched, `(*SKIP*)` tells the engine to "skip" to the next position once the first try of matching succeeded. Then `(*F)` - aka `(*FAIL)` - will tell the engine to act as if the matching failed, in order to retry pattern matching at the current position. More infos [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24535912/4375327). Official PERL doc [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: Another interesting point : is here `preg_replace` more optimized than a couple of str_replace ?

Answer (score 0):

Not using preg_replace, just to give you an idea, my code is not optimized ! (I know)

```
$str = 'xyzdsdasdas@xyss.com';
$buff = explode('@', $str);
$buff2 = explode('.', $buff[1]);

$part1 = $buff[0][0] . str_repeat('*', strlen($buff[0]) - 2) . $buff[0][strlen($buff[0]) - 1];
$part2 = $buff[1][0] . str_repeat('*', strlen($buff2[0]) - 2) . $buff2[0][strlen($buff2[0]) - 1];

echo $part1 .'@'. $part2 .'.'. $buff2[1];
```

But it works.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `preg_replace_callback` function

```
function callbackFunction($m) {
  return $m[1].(str_repeat('*', strlen($m[2]))).$m[3].(str_repeat('*', strlen($m[4]))).$m[5];
}

$pattern = '|^(\\w)(.*?)(.@.)(.*?)(.\\.\\w+)|';
$subject = 'xyzdsdasdas@xyss.com';
print_r( preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'callbackFunction', $subject, -1 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another try, without `explode` :

```
<?php

$email="blablabla@truc.com" ;

$arobase_pos = strpos($email,"@"); // first occurence of "@"
$dot_pos = strrpos($email,".");    // last occurence of ".""

// from 2 to post(@) -1
$email = substr_replace($email, str_repeat ("*", $arobase_pos - 2), 1, $arobase_pos - 2);
// from pos(@)+2 to pos(.)-1 
$email = substr_replace($email, str_repeat ("*", $dot_pos-1-$arobase_pos-2),  $arobase_pos + 2, $dot_pos-1-$arobase_pos-2);

// Display
echo $email;
?>
```